# I have a blog, and I would like to find out the best way to find the most commented posts

Tags: php, mysqli

Am getting this error.
Warning: mysqli_errno() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\comment1\ajax\add-comment.php on line 20

```
<?php
extract($_POST);
if($_POST['act'] == 'add-com'):
    $name = htmlentities($name);
    $email = htmlentities($email);
    $comment = htmlentities($comment);

    // Connect to the database
    include('../config.php'); 

    // Get gravatar Image 
    // https://fr.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/php/
    $default = "mm";
    $size = 35;
    $grav_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) ) . "?d=" . $default . "&s=" . $size;

    if(strlen($name) <= '1'){ $name = 'Guest';}
    //insert the comment in the database
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO comments (name, email, comment, id_post)VALUES( '$name', '$email', '$comment', '$id_post')");
    if(!mysqli_errno()){
?>

    <div class="cmt-cnt">
        <img src="<?php echo $grav_url; ?>" alt="" />
        <div class="thecom">
            <h5><?php echo $name; ?></h5><span  class="com-dt"><?php echo date('d-m-Y H:i'); ?></span>
            <br/>
            <p><?php echo $comment; ?></p>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end "cmt-cnt" -->

    <?php } ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `mysqli_errno` takes a connection as parameter. See the [doc](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_errno.asp) for more info.

So you should use: `mysqli_errno($con)`